# python - kivy: Cómo correr una app sencilla en tu móvil

Tags: python, app, programación-móvil, kivy

supongamos que tengo el programa más sencillo que puede hacerse con kivy:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.button import Button

class TestApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Button(text='Hello World')

TestApp().run()
```

Además de verlo en mi ordenador de sobremesa me gustaría verlo en mi móvil.
¿Qué pasos he de seguir?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Te recomiendo que te mires la documentaación de Kivy al respecto:

[Kivy- Create a package for Android](https://kivy.org/docs/guide/packaging-android.html#packaging-android)

Resumiendo un poco, para crear una apk tienes dos opciones, usar [Buildozer](https://github.com/kivy/buildozer) o directamente [python-for-android](https://github.com/kivy/python-for-android). Crear la app con Buildozer es sencillo y rápido. El problema es que solo funciona bajo sistemas Linux por el momento. Si tienes acceso a un sistema Linux (Ubuntu, Debian, Fedora, etc) puedes seguir los pasos que se describen en la documentación. Si no puedes usar [The Kivy Android Virtual Machine](https://kivy.org/docs/guide/packaging-android-vm.html#kivy-android-vm) y usarla en windows con VirtualBox. Es una distro basada en Ubuntu con todo lo necesario para construir la apk con Buildozer (Android SDK, Android NDK, python-for-android, kivy, python, etc).

No obstante, dado que estas empezando con Kivy, te recomiendo que en su lugar uses [Kivy Launcher](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.kivy.pygame). Te lo descargas desde GooglePlay desde tu teléfono Android y una vez instalado permite lanzar aplicaciones Kivy desde tu Android. Cuando tengas tu aplicación terminada lo mejor es crear la apk con Buildozer pero mientras la desarrollas o incluso para usarla tu a nivel personal esta opción es muy buena ya que permite modificar la app simplemte copiando y pegando los archivos (.py, .kv, imágenes, etc) en el teléfono sin tener que volver a compilar el apk.

Para usar Kivy Launcher debes:

- El módulo principal de tu app debe llamarse `main.py`.
- Necesitas un archivo de texto con la configuración de tu app, llamado `android.txt` y que tiene que contener como mínimo:

  ```
  title=Nombre de tu app
  author=Tu nombre
  orientation=portrait|landscape
  ```
- Ahora te vas a tu teléfono, buscas la carperta `/sdcard/kivy/` y creas dentro otra carpeta con el nombre de tu aplicación. Dentro de ella pegas los dos archivos anteriores(toda la app en realidad: módulos .py, archivos de kivy languaje, iconos, videos, etc van también aquí).
- Ahora simplemente abres la app Kivy Launcher y te aparecerá una lista de aplicaciones (vienen unas cuantas de ejemplo con la instalación). Seleccionas la tuya y debe correr sin problemas si todo es correcto.

Para tu ejemplo simple:

- Creas un archivo `android.txt` que contenga algo así:

  ```
  title=MyApp
  author=Baldan
  orientation=landscape
  ```
- Guardas el código que aportas como `main.py`.
- Conectas el teléfono al pc, buscas la carpeta kivy, creas dentro una nueva carpeta llamada MyApp y metes dentro los dos archivos anteriores.
- Te vas a tu teléfono y lanzas Kivy Launcher, seleccionas MyApp y ya está:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Todo funciona ok... gracias por tu valiosa información

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar [pydroid](/questions/tagged/pydroid) que te servirá como intérprete de Python y puedes probar tus apps ahí sin compilar ni necesidad de nada.. simple

Comment: La respuesta anterior no es "mucho diálogo", es una respuesta _bien redactada_. Lee [answer] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.