# Como pasar De.py a .apk

Tags: python, android

buenos días:
Me gustaría saber como puedo compilar mi script de python, para poder ejecutarlo en mi Android (version 10).
No se si importa pero el script no es gran cosa solo utiliza tkinter y no lleva ningún material multimedia es solo para probar es un contador. Mi pc es un iMac con la versión BigSur
Saludos, gracias

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [python - kivy: Cómo correr una app sencilla en tu móvil](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/62825/python-kivy-c%c3%b3mo-correr-una-app-sencilla-en-tu-m%c3%b3vil)

Comment: Aunque no generarás un *apk*, puedes utilizar [pydroid3](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=ru.iiec.pydroid3) para ejecutar *scripts Python que utilizan Tkinter* en *Android*. Si el *apk* es una prioridad debes ir a por *Kivy* como ha dicho @JuanRivera en el primer comentario, pero no podrás usar *Tkinter*.

Comment: Creo que es importante mostrar o comentar que realiza el script. ¿Que visualizaras en la app Android?

Comment: Gracias a los tres, intentaré apañarme con lo de Kivy de todas maneras lo de pydroid3 también es una buena solución ¿@Jorgesys quieres que te pase el código?